# Binding function result in "when" expression - F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm writing a match, where I'm limiting the matching base on a function f, using the "when" expression. I'd like to bind the result of f for use in the following expression. I'd like my code to look something like this:

```
match input with
| input when f x input -> //Some exp where (f x input) is used but not recomputed
| input when f y input -> //Some exp where (f x input) is used but not recomputed
```

The obvious solution is to simply recompute the result, but I'm wondering if there's an alternative mechanism i can use.

Comment: You don't need to recompute the result: if the pattern matched, you know that `f x input = true`

Comment: In this example, `f` must be a boolean for `when f x input` to compile without errors. If you want `f` to be a function returning some arbitrary type, you want [active patterns](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-active-patterns/). Look in particular at the `Int` and `Bool` examples: if the result of the active pattern is `Some x`, then matching it as `Int y` assigns the value `x` to `y`. If that doesn't make sense yet, read the article and experiment a bit.

Comment: Or just use an `if` expression instead. Just because you have a fancy hammer doesn't mean that everything has to be a nail.

Answer (score 0):

The result of f in the following expression is "true". You can just use true if you want. If you're looking to match and transform the match in some way you can use active patterns.

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let (|FirstRegexGroup|_|) pattern input =
   let m = Regex.Match(input,pattern) 
   if (m.Success) then Some m.Groups.[1].Value else None  

let testRegex str = 
    match str with
    | FirstRegexGroup "http://(.*?)/(.*)" host -> 
           printfn "The value is a url and the host is %s" host
    | FirstRegexGroup ".*?@(.*)" host -> 
           printfn "The value is an email and the host is %s" host
    | _ -> printfn "The value '%s' is something else" str

// test
testRegex "http://google.com/test"
testRegex "alice@hotmail.com"
```

source https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-active-patterns/